# Get all instances of a type of a control based on a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, controls

Is there a way to get all instances of a specific control type based on some other information. Normally I would use;

```
       public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllControlsOfType<T>(this Control parent) where T : Control
    {
        var result = new List<T>();

        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (control is T)
            {
                result.Add((T)control);
            }
            if (control.HasControls())
            {
                result.AddRange(control.GetAllControlsOfType<T>());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But this wont work because I don't know ahead of time which control type I will be looking for.

Comment: What do you know ahead of time then? Will you have an instance of the type at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you only know the type at runtime then you can use [Type.IsInstanceOfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx)
 instead of "control is T" in your example. The function would require a Type parameter and return an IEnumerable<Control>.